# Getting wrong output from DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm getting last week dates from below code, week starts with Saturday. It's getting dates(2019-04-27 18:30:00 +0000, 019-05-04 18:30:00 +0000), but when i try to set **DateFormatter** it's getting dates(28-04-2019 00:00:00, 05-05-2019 00:00:00). I want week starts with with Monday in india local time & date.

```
var dateFormatter:DateFormatter!
var date:Date!

dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
date = Date()

var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday
let lastWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())
if let lastWeek = lastWeek {
var startOfLastWeek = Date()
var interval = TimeInterval(0)

_ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfLastWeek, interval: &interval, for: lastWeek)
let endOfLastWeek = startOfLastWeek.addingTimeInterval(interval)
print(startOfLastWeek)//2019-04-27 18:30:00 +0000
print(endOfLastWeek)//019-05-04 18:30:00 +0000

let startWeekString = dateFormatter.string(from: startOfLastWeek)
let endWeekString = dateFormatter.string(from: endOfLastWeek)
print(startWeekString)//28-04-2019 00:00:00
print(endWeekString)//05-05-2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: @ rmaddy, thank you. How get my local time(india) with proper output along with date formatter.

Comment: @rmaddy, I understood your words but how can I get last week dates in local time or How to convert UTC time in required formate with out **DateFormatter**.

Comment: When I try to set **DateFormatter** week starting with Tuesday not Monday. But with out DateFormatter week starting with Monday. Finally i want week starts with  Monday and formate is 05-05-2019 00:00:00

Comment: I fixed this issue with to set **TimeZone** in to ** UTC**. dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" dateformatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

Comment: @ rmaddy, yes you right, when I set DateFormatter in to UTC it's getting same date. But I want local time and date.

Comment: Try to set `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current`, `dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current`. It will set the timezone and locale according to the region in which the app is running. In India, it will set it to Indian Standard Time(IST).

Comment: @ Anshul Bhatheja, no use getting same problem. dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current

Comment: @iOS What is the actual result you want? What is wrong with the result of `28-04-2019 00:00:00` and `05-05-2019 00:00`? What values do you actually want?

Comment: @rmaddy, 28-04-2019 in Tuesday in india, I want Monday date as for Indian time. In india last week started with 27-04-2019 (Monday). I want this date as last week start day and same like end day is 02-05-2019(Sunday).

Comment: What? 28-04-2019 (April 28) is a Sunday in any country. And 27-04-2019 (April 27) is a Saturday in any country. If you want Monday, you want 29-04-2019 (April 29).

Comment: @ rmaddy , sorry 29-04-2019 - 05-05-2019

Comment: Now that we've had this overly long discussion, please [edit] your question to include the specific fact that instead of `28-04-2019 00:00:00` and `05-05-2019 00:00` for the output, you actually want `29-04-2019 00:00:00`. And explain why. Then we can delete all of these comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` is always in UTC in any programming language, It does't have time zones. And `DateFormatter` is used to show `Date` in local/localised format by providing timezones.

The `Date Formatter` allow you to convert it to string that is human readable.
In phones:

1. If you have central server/DB then you should save you Dates in UTC.
2. when time to show on your phone, convert UTC to local using time zone.

DO NOT TRY TO OVERCOMPLICATE IT.

**Use below code to find Monday and Sunday of last week:**

```
var date:Date!

dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone=TimeZone.current
TimeZone.current
date = Date()

var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday
let lastWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())
if let lastWeek = lastWeek {
 var startOfLastWeek = Date()
 var interval = TimeInterval(0)

 _ = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, start: &startOfLastWeek, interval: &interval, for: lastWeek)
 startOfLastWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekday, value: 1, to: startOfLastWeek)!
 print(interval)
 interval = interval - 1
 let endOfLastWeek = startOfLastWeek.addingTimeInterval(interval)
 print(startOfLastWeek)//2019-04-27 18:30:00 +0000
 print(endOfLastWeek)//019-05-04 18:30:00 +0000

 let startWeekString = dateFormatter.string(from: startOfLastWeek)
 let endWeekString = dateFormatter.string(from: endOfLastWeek)
 print(startWeekString)//28-04-2019 00:00:00
 print(endWeekString)//05-05-2019 00:00:00
}
```

Comment: thank you. I'm converting date in to local with DateFormatter, but here getting week staring with Tuesday , but I want Monday. Can you solve above code for me.

Comment: Check edited answer. It may be workaround but will solve your problem

Comment: 05-05-2019 00:00:00 in Sunday it's ok, but want week first day date(Here Week starts with Monday onwards). So the date 28-04-2019 00:00:00 to 29-04-2019 we required.

Comment: Check edited 2. You have to increment `startOfLastWeek`. @rmaddy suggestion is right that you want startOfWeak as monday of every week and endOfWeek as sunday of every week. Just write function to find monday and sunday of weak. It make sense.

Comment: @Akshay Please rewrite your answer without any edits so it reads as a nice clean, final answer.